# Code Coverage for Database Projects

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage

Is it possible to get code coverage results of Database Unit Tests for a Database Project in Visual Studio 2010?
Thanks.

Comment: What would you expect to see in the report?

Comment: @Shaun Wilde - at a minimum I'd want to see a report that listed things like: number of Database Unit Tests, number of tests passed, number failed, names of failing tests, hyperlinks to each stored procedure or view under test.

Comment: @JeffH - surely that is what the test tool reports